# Selenium Webdriver stops running after Sikuli script

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, sikuli

I'm trying to run a simple java script with Selenium Webdriver, but I also had to use Sikuli because the testing requires to open and interact with a browser extension. My problem is that the Webdriver test stops running after the Sikuli script.

I tried to switch to default content with: `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`, but it doesn't work.
Does somebody know how to keep running the Webdriver test? Following you can see a template of my test:

```
public class LoginTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed{

    //Add the extension code in the project
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions ();
    options.addExtensions (new File
            ("Path to the extension"));
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities ();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    driver.get("chrome-extension"); 

    //Login on a website + extension
        driver.get("url");
        driver.findElement(By.id("nav-login-link")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.name("auth_id")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.name("auth_secret")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.className("button-wrapper")).click();

    //Opens the Extension with Sikuli and continues on browser
        Screen screen = new Screen();

        screen.find("icon.png");
        screen.click("icon.png");
        screen.click("icon.png");
        screen.wait("popup.png");
        screen.click("selector.png");
        screen.click("search.png");
        screen.type("country.png");
        screen.click("flag.png");
        screen.click("browser.png");
        screen.type("url"+Key.ENTER);

    //Interact on browser with Webdriver - Login (*HERE IS WHERE THE THE TEST STOPS RUNNING*)
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/login']")).click();
}
}
```

Comment: when you say "stops running", what actually happens? Exception? Error?

Comment: Nothing happens at all, the Sikuli code is run and that's the end of it. The latest console entry shows the Sikuli last action as successful, but nothing else. Should I create a new test method? I want to continue the test on the same browser though.

Comment: First, there is no need to switch context in this case. Second, are you certain that the last part works just by itself? I see you have a timeout which is good and there is no way Sikuli is interfering with Selenium execution so it must be something with the last part itself. Moreover, if this xpath was wrong you'd get an `NoSuchElement` exception which as I understand is not the case.

Comment: Actually I waited a little bit longer after the SIkuli execution and I get a `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException:` on the following element: `*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//a[@href='/login']}`. However, if I run this code as a separate test in another Java class, it works fine. (please note that the URL given in the last sikuli step takes like 5/6 seconds to load, this is before the last selenium part)

Comment: Following the comment above, apparently the exception doesn't have anything to do with the Element, I have modified the last part of the code and I still get the error right after Sikuli runs. This is the actual exception: `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 600.000
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`